# Missing requirement package in OSGI Bundle - Felix & Servicemix

Tags: maven, osgi, apache-felix, osgi-bundle, apache-servicemix

I have spent a few days trying to understand how to deploy as OSGI bundle and need some help.  I am using servicemix 4.5.2, maven 3.1.0 and maven-bundle-plugin 2.4.0.  I have added the following tags in my .pom

```
<Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime</Embed-Dependency>    
<Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
```

My bundle builds and when I deploy into servicemix, I get a series of BundleExceptions.  I iteratively add the missing packages to my pom until I hit a wall. "Missing requirement package; (package=com.ibm.ejs.ras)".  The immediate issue is that I can't find the ras.jar to download or in a Maven repository. But I think the larger issue is that I am doing something incorrectly that is resulting in my having to manually track down transitive dependencies.

I have dug around and saw that common issues were resolved by using the pre-bundled versions from Spring and Fuse. The Fuse repository appears to have vanished and the Spring one seems to be sun-setting and doesn't have all the .jars I need.  I also tried the bundleall maven-bundle-plugin which I saw on another post the goal is now deprecated). That resulted in "Error generating OSGi bundle for project org.beanshell:bsh-core: aQute.bnd.osgi.Descriptors$PackageRef cannot be cast to java.lang.String".

I have used previous (pre-OSGI) versions of servicemix and camel and have high regard for both products. However, I am losing steam (and work time) trying to get over the OSGI hurdle and Mule is becoming more attractive. If anyone has some insights, they would be greatly appreciated.

Thank-you.

My pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.abc</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>myartifact</artifactId>
<packaging>bundle</packaging>
<name>myartifact</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>         
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-mail</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-dao</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.35.0</version>
    </dependency>           
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>    
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <instructions>
            <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
            <Bundle-Description>${project.description}</Bundle-Description>
            <Export-Package>com.mycompany.abc.myartifact</Export-Package>
            <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime</Embed-Dependency>    
            <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
          </instructions>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>          
</build>
```

Comment: You probably should not bother embedding spring and camel jars in your bundles. There are spring and camel features for Karaf and ServiceMix (though probably not for Spring 2.0.x). That said, I'll be adding a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

com.ibm.ejs.ras is probably an optional dependency to one of the JARS you have bundled in.

You would update your Import-Package to filter out the offending package.

```
<Import-Package>!com.ibm.ejs.ras, *</Import-Package>.
```

Also:

Embed-Dependency uses Bundle-Classpath under the hood. I'd defer to the creator of the tool that is enabling you to do this: http://www.aqute.biz/Bnd/FAQ#bundleclasspath

I would definitely agree that Embed-Dependency is definitely not necessary in this case, considering you are using ServiceMix which comes with 90% of what you are needing in this case anyway. The rest can be installed within ServiceMix itself using mvn: or wrap:mvn: style-urls. (which is only dbcp and lang3 and selenium)